# a problem with using accessors in laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to use created_at field in two different type

```
 public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $time = new \Verta($value);
    return $time->formatDifference();
}
```

this is my code and I need to use default created_at value as well

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make another accessor with a different name (`created_at_diff` perhaps) for your special format:

```
public function getCreatedAtDiff()
{
    return (new \Verta($this->attributes['created_at']))->formatDifference();

    // or $this->created_at instead of $this->attributes['created_at']
}
```

Then you can access it via `$model->created_at_diff`.